# Post image files to GoogleDrive from R?

Tags: r

I've been working with a nice dynamic dataset where I get data from a spreadsheet on GoogleDrive and analyze it in R. No issues there. Is there a way of serving some figures (i.e., some image files) back to GoogleDrive? This can be done in PHP (and Python I imagine). Any idea of whether this can be done directly in R? I.e., given

```
png(filename = "foo.png")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Can I upload foo.png to GoogleDrive from within an R script?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you have in mind, but this may help http://www.r-bloggers.com/download-all-documents-from-google-drive-with-r/

Comment: Can't this be accomplished locally?  Sending it to your local drive?